# Warning: you may need to increase the main.cf smtp_destination_concurrency_limit - but it is set?

Tags: postfix, smtp

We have a huge delivery of emails right now and emails are not delivered as fast as I think they would:

In the mail log (Postfix v3.4.13 ) I see the following message

```
Dec  8 14:34:28 s29 postfix/qmgr[2773433]: warning: mail for iu-mail.org is using up 20000 of 20000 active queue entries 
Dec  8 14:34:28 s29 postfix/qmgr[2773433]: warning: you may need to increase the main.cf smtp_destination_concurrency_limit from 1 
Dec  8 14:34:28 s29 postfix/qmgr[2773433]: warning: please avoid flushing the whole queue when you have 
Dec  8 14:34:28 s29 postfix/qmgr[2773433]: warning: lots of deferred mail, that is bad for performance 
Dec  8 14:34:28 s29 postfix/qmgr[2773433]: warning: to turn off these warnings specify: qmgr_clog_warn_time = 0
```

I checked my main.conf but it clearly sets

```
smtp_destination_concurrency_limit = 10
smtp_destination_rate_delay = 1s
smtp_extra_recipient_limit = 10
```

I have no clue where the value of 1 is coming from. Do you have any ideas what to check to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Ugh. Figured it out:

Setting a `smtp_destination_rate_delay` forces the value for concurrency automatically to 1.
Removing that parameter resolved the issue.